# Flash Actionscript 3.0 "Enter" Key Causes scene to change

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, keyboard, scene

I am creating a Flash game.  Unfortunately, when the Player presses "Enter," the game continuously cycles through its scenes.  I tried the following (although I know it's a bit buckshee):

```
            // The Enter Key was pressed
            // If the Enter key is pressed, the keyboard input is "changed" to
                // be '.'.  This prevents a problem in which the Player would
                // press 'Enter' and the game screen would continuously cycle
                // through scenes
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER) {
            // The 'PERIOD' key does nothing
            event.keyCode = Keyboard.PERIOD;
            //spaceKeyPressed = true;
        }
```

Is there a way to prevent 'Enter' from cycling through the scenes?

Thanks,

Christian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While testing your game with *Test Movie* inside Flash Professional, select "***Disable Keyboard Shortcuts***" from the *Control* menu, Otherwise, as you can see in the *Control* menu, the first item is "*Play*" which has the *Enter* key as the keyboard shortcut.

Note that the items in the *Control* menu change depending on if you are currently testing a movie or not.  You will only see the menu from the screenshot below while you are testing your game.

[image]