# ENTER key going to next scene. Adobe animate, actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, animate-cc

So I have a quiz on frame one of scene one.  When the user gets a certain number of questions right it goes to scene two.

However the problem is if the user presses enter it skips the whole quiz an goes straight to scene two.

Any ideas on how to disable this? Flash Cc had a disable keyboard shortcuts under the control panel but it's been taken out in animate..

Also, I have a eventlistener on the enter key but it's still ignoring it and skipping the scene =(

Comment: Post the code you are having problems with, please.

Comment: Hi Neal, 

Basically the same code as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246556/flash-actionscript-3-0-enter-key-causes-scene-to-change

However, Adobe Animate must need a different solution to fix this, as the "Disable keyboard shortcut" option is unavailable.

Comment: Try testing the movie in your browser instead. I believe the keyboard shortcuts only work when testing the movie in animate. I believe the option to turn off shortcuts was deprecated with animate, as you have surmised. And since it's only a feature during testing, it shouldn't cause a problem for end users (I'm pretty sure).